# Understand php's key-value pair from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, key-value

I wanted to understand the way key-value pairs are organised. For example, in the wp_postmeta table of wordpress we have the following in meta_value column, which is probably indicating from where and how images for a given slideshow would be fetched.

Any tips on how can I get references of the images there ? Probably I could do something similar to var_dump or print_r here ?

```
a:3:{i:1;a:6:{s:5:"title";s:39:""Femme de l'économie" les hommes bleus";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:9:"urlTarget";s:5:"_self";s:4:"type";s:10:"attachment";s:6:"postId";s:5:"10391";}i:2;a:6:{s:5:"title";s:41:""Femme de l'économie" les hommes oranges";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:9:"urlTarget";s:5:"_self";s:4:"type";s:10:"attachment";s:6:"postId";s:5:"10392";}i:3;a:6:{s:5:"title";s:31:""Femme de l'économie" les arts";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:9:"urlTarget";s:5:"_self";s:4:"type";s:10:"attachment";s:6:"postId";s:5:"10393";}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [serialized string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). In order to be able to store arrays or objects in the database, WordPress has to transform them into strings.

Normally, you should not need to [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it manually, because WordPress does that for you if you're using their API to get that data in the first place (for eg. through `get_option()` or `$wpdb` methods). In this case you're probably looking for [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: If OP aim is to READ and understand as opposed to actually use it in code , maybe he can use wp´s `maybe_unserialize()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize

Comment: Thanks Obmerk. In this particular case, Pony's solution is working perfectly for me.